# how to make graph

Tags: python

i want to make graph using matplotlib in python.

np.load(name.npy')

i searched many things and i tried 
for example..just...

```
x = [dt.datetime(2003, 05, 01), dt.datetime(2008, 06, 01)]
df = np.load(r'file')
y = df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the end date on the date-range to your desired graph, and the 'y' should be array loaded

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start_date = '2003-05-01'
y = np.load(r'c:\python27\abnormal.npy')
x = pd.date_range(start=start_date, periods=len(y), freq='D')


plt.plot(x,y,'.')
plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you, you comment. now, i know how to time series
however, in here
y = np.random.randint(0,high=5,size=len(x))
 ''y' should be array loaded' what mean?
how to input npy file vaules in y??

Comment: Then your start and end dates are incorrect. I've edited the code to work as long as you have the correct start date (assuming you have data for every day)

Answer (score 1):

If your input array does not contain ordered pairs such as `[(0,1), (1,1), (2,2)]` and only contains one set of numbers '[1, 2, 3, 4]`, you neeed to create a set of x-coordinates. For a time series in days, you could try something like this:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def getData(fileName):
    # Load the data file to serve as y-axis coordinates
    y = np.load(fileName)

    # For each y coordinate we need an x coordinate
    time_offset = list(range(len(y)))

    # Convert time_offset to a time-series
    # We will assume x-values equal number of days since a beginDate
    x = []
    beginDate = datetime.date(2015, 6, 1) # The date to begin our time series
    for n in time_offset:
        date = beginDate + datetime.timedelta(n) # Date + number_of_Days_passed
        x.append(date)

    return x, y



def plot(x, y):
    # Plot the data
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1)

    ax.scatter(x, y)
    for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
                label.set_rotation(90)

    ax.grid(True)

    plt.subplots_adjust(left=.10, bottom=.19, right=.93, top=.95, wspace=.20, hspace=0)
    plt.show()


x, y = getData('abnormal.npy')
plot(x, y)
```